# Pick From Drop-Down List Using XLwings in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have an Excel sheet with a few cells locked with data validation using a drop-down list. I want to give a value to those cells using XLwings. I have seen some similar questions, but nothing solves my issue.

I tried with:

```
app = xw.App(visible=True)
wb = app.books.open(copy_file)
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
list = sht.range('C21').api.Validation.Formula1[1:]
```

Honestly I don't know how that last line is supposed to work, I found it at https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/901.
When I try to run it, it just throws an error in xlwindows.py and stops the code.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but after looking at the link you posted, I think the problem is that you're trying to set a range (the [1:] part means from index 1 to the end, not a single value).  In the example from the link, it is asking for those values to be *returned*, so that was OK.  But you're trying to *set* the value, and you can't set a drop-down menu to an entire range.  Delete the ':' and you might have more success.